# Segue is being executed twice

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   self.selectedClubState = stateNamesForDisplay[indexPath.row]
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier ("Cities", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var clubsToPassToCitiesViewController = [clubObject]()
    if segue.identifier == "Cities" {
        for club in clubsForTable{
            if club.clubState == self.selectedClubState{
                clubsToPassToCitiesViewController.append(club)
            }
        }
       let citiesView = segue.destinationViewController as? citiesViewController
       citiesView?.clubsForChosenCity = clubsToPassToCitiesViewController
   }
}
```

Segue is being executed twice leading to the next VC. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 19):

Delete the current segue in storyboard. Then CTRL-drag **from the viewController** (not the cell) to the next view controller and name it "Cities". Now, when you select a cell, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` will fire first and will call `performSegueWithIdentifier()`

[image]

However, if all you're looking to do in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` is get the row that performed the segue, you can maintain your original setup of having the cell segue from the storyboard, remove `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` and in `prepareForSegue()` do:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        self.selectedClubState = stateNamesForDisplay[indexPath.row]
    }
    var clubsToPassToCitiesViewController = [clubObject]()
    if segue.identifier == "Cities" {
        for club in clubsForTable{
            if club.clubState == self.selectedClubState{
                clubsToPassToCitiesViewController.append(club)
            }
        }
       let citiesView = segue.destinationViewController as? citiesViewController
       citiesView?.clubsForChosenCity = clubsToPassToCitiesViewController
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shades I just had to delete my segue from the cell and drag one from the storyboard!

Comment: Exactly, and when drag from storyboard it worked for me too even if I still have performSegue on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath() ` method :) tested on Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 14):

*You* are the one executing the segue twice — once automatically in the storyboard (because your segue emanates as an Action Segue from the cell prototype), and once in code when you say `self.performSegueWithIdentifier`. If you don't want the segue executed twice, remove one of those.

Personally, my recommendation is that you delete `didSelectRow` entirely and move your `self.selectedClubState` assignment into `prepareForSegue`.