# Swift Passing data from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm new to Swift, and was thrilled to find that we no longer need delegates and protocols to send a chunk of data to another view controller.

However, using this code:

```
...

class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var detailPicPath: String?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let detailPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "account = %@", currentAccount)
    let transactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self).filter(detailPredicate)
    let orderedTransactions = transactions.sorted(byKeyPath: "transDate", ascending: false)
    let item = orderedTransactions[indexPath.row]
    detailPicPath = item.picPath

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "microSegue", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

and this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "microSegue" {
        let destination: MicroDetailViewController = segue.destination as! MicroDetailViewController
        destination.picPathForThisTrans = detailPicPath

}
```

I get `nil` in `destination.picPathForThisTrans`, and a crash with this warning:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

at the point where `picPathForThisTrans` is called in the destination view controller.

I've searched SO and Google (which usually leads back to SO) but haven't found a solution. I'm wondering if I'm defining my `var`s correctly.

Could sure use some guidance!

TIA

**Edit**

Upon reading the post referenced below by @rmaddy, I revisited my issue and discovered that the problem was not with the saving of properties nor how they were unwrapped. While these are issues with which I certainly need more experience, the problem was caused by a more fundamental oversight--I was using both a Storyboard `segue`, and one called in code. In the storyboard `segue`, `prepareForSegue` wasn't in possession of the relevant information. Since it was apparently called after the programmatic method, it overwrote the data in the receiver, resulting in `nil` at the critical point.

I discovered this issue when I found (using a whole bunch of `print()` statements) that `prepareForSegue` was being called twice, once when it was loaded, and once unloaded.

Doing some further research, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335120/segue-is-being-executed-twice), which enabled me to fix the issue. Many thanks to @rmaddy and to those who contributed to the post mentioned relating to `segue`s!

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, see [the last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818897/1226963).

Comment: Am reading it now! Tks!

Comment: Please see edit! And thanks again!